# Reset positioning HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I tried to create a special effect in the background of my website for which I used some `div`which are overlaped. Now the page with the content itself should be placed over this background again. But if I set it to `position: absolute` and add `top:0` the page isn't centered again cause the `margin:0 auto` doesn't work with the absolute position.

[I put it online, so you can have a look on it...](http://eckstein.be/r/position-problem/)

The dark grey navigation bar should be at the top of the site. How can I do this? I'm really confused rightnow... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post your code along with the source link so we can diagnose quicker.  :)

Comment: Include the header before `#hero-image-container`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see any 'dark grey nav' on your link? The 'back to top' arrow? ..nevermind I see it, yes change to 'absolute' as answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
#hero-image {
    position: relative;
```

To:

```
#hero-image {
    position: absolute;
```

And better yet, you're probably better off add that image as a `background-image` attribute to `<body>` rather than as a positioned element.

Comment: Thank you! I tried so many things, but it would have been so easy... I'm feeling a little bit stupid now... :D (I'll accept this as the right answer when stackoverflow let me do this... )

Comment: No worries. It happens to the best of us. :) If you do continue to use SO, please consider including your markup and CSS  in your question. It's a standard/required practice and there are some who will downvote questions that lack these criteria.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a width as absolute element, you can try applying the next solution:

```
.divtagExample{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:300px;
    positon:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

That way it should work for you.

However, if you want to make it center vertically and horizontally then just expand this to `top: 0;` `bottom: 0;` combine this with a CSS three transition for `width` and `height` and you will have a great effect.

## Explanation

You can also understand this by going to the next links:

- [Margins and Absolute Positioning](http://web.archive.org/web/20130117135705/http://www.vision.to/articles/margins-and-absolute-positioning.php)
- [Margins and absolute positioning don't worktogether - Macromedia Dynamic HTML](http://www.justskins.com/forums/css-margins-and-absolute-82168.html)

Comment: Tanks for the links. I'll definitive have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the nav bar on top, just add: `top:0`